# List taxonomies in a dropdown in theme's option panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I want to show a dropdown in the option's panel for choosing a "featured product category" which is a custom taxonomy.
I do this way:

```
register_taxonomy("Catalogs",
    array("kmproduct"),
    array("hierarchical" => true,
          "label" => "Catalogs",
          "singular_label" => "catalog",
          "rewrite" => true   ));
```

and in my `theme_options.php` i have:

```
...
array( "name" => "Homepage featured category",  
      "desc" => "Choose a category from which featured posts are drawn", 
      "id" => $shortname."_feat_cat",  
      "type" => "select",  
      "options" => $wp_tax,  
      "std" => "Choose a category"),
```

and I can't get the taxonomies list:

```
$args=array(   'name' => 'Catalogs');

$output = 'names'; // or objects    
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args,$output);

$wp_tax = array();  
foreach ($taxonomies as $category_list ) {  
     $wp_tax[$category_list->ID] = $category_list->name; 
}

array_unshift($wp_tax, "Choose a category");
```

What's wrong? I can't get it to work :(

Comment: Are you looking for a list of *terms*, or a list of *taxonomies*? It sounds like you might have a confusion in terms (pun completely unintentional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *taxonomy* is a group of *terms*. I think you registered a taxonomy *Catalogs*, and now you want to list all terms in this taxonomy. You do that with the function [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms), not [`get_taxonomies()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies).

So your `$wp_tax` array should be filled like this:

```
$wp_tax = array(-1 => 'Choose a category');
$catalog_terms = get_terms('Catalogs');
if ($catalog_terms) {
    foreach ($catalog_terms as $catalog_term) {
        $wp_tax[$catalog_term->term_id] = $catalog_term->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works!!!! :) Thank you very much.

My first try was with "$taxonomies = get_terms('theme', 'hide_empty=0');" and obviously it didn't work.